# Select-String RegEx how to select only '}' in this example

Tags: powershell, select-string

Lets say I have string like so:

```
foo
}
bar}
    }
{baz}
```

and I only want to match closing braces that  are at the start of a line or are preceded by a white space such as one or more  `tab` characters.

So with the above sample, only the braces at line 2 and 4 should be selected (counting from 1)

This first attempt seems to only highlight, the closing brace at line 2, the brace at line 4 is not selected:

```
"foo
}
bar}
    }
{baz}" |Select-String "\n\s?\}" -AllMatches
```

I tried making the whitespace token optional with `?`, but then the brace at line 2 is deselected:

```
"foo
}
bar}
    }
{baz}" |Select-String "\n\s+?\}" -AllMatches
```

hmm...I am pretty sure I would have succeeded with `-replace` or `-match` by now but I really need to get the hang of `Select-String`.

Comment: This pattern should work: `'(?<=^|\s)\}'` but you should use an input file since PowerShell takes a string like this or even a here string as one line. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
"foo
}
bar}
    }
{baz}" | Select-String '(?m)^[ \t]*\}' -AllMatches
```

- Use inline option `(?m)` to make `^` (and `$`) match the start (and end) of *each line*.
- Use `[ \t]*` to match any run of *zero or more* (`*`) spaces or tabs (`[ \t]`)

  - Note: `\s*`, for matching all *whitespace* chars., would potentially match *across lines*, given that newlines are whitespace too.